# ARkit - SceneKit : Dynamically Placing 3D models on a detected plane

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am working on ARKit project and trying to place some objects on a detected plane. But it doesn't work properly once i move the device to place an other object, the first object doesn't stand on his position. I want that every rendered object be stuck in the first position until the user start interacting with it.

I already see this:

[ARKIT : place object on a plane doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544204/arkit-place-object-on-a-plane-doesnt-work-properly)

But there is no solution yet.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        self.planeAnchor = planeAnchor
        self.floorNode = node

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.messageLabel.text = "Surface Detectée - Taper + pour choisir des objets"
            self.addModelButton.isEnabled = true
            self.addModelButton.alpha = 1
        }

    }


 func addFurniture(selectedNode:SCNNode) {

        selectedNode.simdPosition = float3(planeAnchor.center.x, planeAnchor.center.y, planeAnchor.center.z)
        floorNode.addChildNode(selectedNode)
        messageLabel.text = "Model chargé - Vous pouvez le positionner, le faire tourner ou ajouter d'autres. "
    }
```

Once the plane is detected, the user select a model from a collectionView then the model is placed in the detected plane once addFurniture(selectedNode:SCNNode) is called.

What am I doing wrong or what I'm not doing ? please can any one help me ?

Comment: might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020192/how-to-keep-arkit-scnnode-in-place

Comment: have you store the position of model object in a local?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS : Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @SaurabhJain No i'm rendring it at the simdPosition of the plane anchor then the user can interact by changing the model position. I'm using UIGestureRecognizer for that.

Comment: @GhachemBouthaina please check the gagan_iOS link